# How do you dynamically assign a function to an element's onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid

As opposed to setting individual functions to each element's click event, I would like to iterate elements and assign based on id or whatever?

```
document.getElementById('measure').onclick = function() { clickMe(1); };
```

How would I approach this?

Comment: Try to assign functions to variables like `var clickMe = function() { //do something };` and then `document.getElementById('measure').onclick  = clickMe`

Comment: why not use one function that will accept an id for its parameter then do your conditions on the function

Comment: Try using class, You can group elements with simmilar functionality and write an event accordingly, its  jquery

Comment: You can try and build on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/U5FvG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've done something along these lines:

```
var setClickOnElements = function(selector) {
    $(selector).each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(event) {
            // behaviour on click
        });
    });
};
```

...where `selector` is a class selector, e.g. `.my-class`.  Within the callback passed to `each` you can get at other properties of the selected elements, e.g. id etc.  If you add that class to the elements you'd like to set a `click` function and call `setClickOnElements('.my-class');` on load, you should be good to go!

**EDIT:** The above uses jQuery. If you're restricted to pure Javascript, you could use one of the methods described in John Resig's post on implementations of `getElementByClass`: http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/

Here's an example (using Dustin Diaz's method from http://www.dustindiaz.com/getelementsbyclass):

```
var getElementsByClass = function(searchClass,node,tag) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    if ( node == null )
        node = document;
    if ( tag == null )
        tag = '*';
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)");
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
            classElements[j] = els[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return classElements;
}

var setClickOnElements = function(className) {
    var elements = getElementsByClass(className);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        element.onclick = function(event) {
            // click behaviour here
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: I think the OP needs something in JS